# Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070057 (E_INVALIDARG) on DSL Designer Visual Studio 2013

Tags: visual-studio-2013, dsl, dsl-tools

I have developed a modeling tool based on DSL, every things was fine with no problem, but suddenly when I right click on the model first I get `"Value does not fall within the expected range."` error and after clicking again I get `"Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070057 (E_INVALIDARG)"` error.

I have emptied `"C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\"` and `"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files"`

- I have restarted my pc
- Resetting Visual studio by devenv /resetsettings
- I have removed and reinstalled my VSIX package
- I have repaired Microsoft .Net framework 4.5.1
- I have repaired Visual Studio SDK
- I have repaired Visual Studio 2013
- I have removed .net framework, visual studio, vs sdk completely and reinstalled them

But I still get the error.

### Solution

Finally I overcome the problem: The problem was caused by having different GUIDs in `DslPackage\GeneratedCode\GeneratedVSCT.tt` and  `DslPackage\GeneratedCode\Constants.tt[CommandSetId]` while they should be same.

Comment: That really isn't enough to go on. What DSL? What code? What right click handler? Where is the error located?

Comment: @david.pfx This is my custom dsl, when I right click on model, the error is in a message box and pops when I right click.
I just want a way to dubug and see what is the cause of exception.